# XCode Application Loader - ERROR ITMS-9000 Invalid Provisioning Profile

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile, application-loader

When I try to upload my iOS application to the app store using the application loader, I get the following errors:

[image: ERROR ITMS-9000]

This means that the provisioning profile is invalid. So, I deleted and re-made the provisioning profile, then archived the application using that profile, and I still got this error... I have uploaded this application to `iTunesConnect` before, and I got no errors, but now, even though I didn't do anything with my profiles, or change it in the application, I'm getting this error.

I have valid and non-expired certificates, and my bundle ID's are correct. The distribution provisioning profiles I have are:

[image: Look at SloganGen]

This is happening for my application named `SloganGen`.

Comment: It's definitely an AppStore distribution profile and not Ad Hoc?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman yes it is

Comment: Check the profile yourself: in Organizer, select archive > Distribute > Save for Enterprise or Ad Hoc > Select AppStore profile + Export. Save IPA somewhere, unzip it, and have a look at the profile with security cms -D -i your.app/embedded.mobileprovision - check that everything looks right, that' there's a dev certificate

Comment: I see `embedded.mobileprovision` in there, I don't know how to open it up though

Comment: Use this command: security cms -D -i your.app/embedded.mobileprovision

Comment: @RhythmicFistman I get a ton of random data which is just random letters and numbers like `61B8G8GT` and stuff like that, then I see:   `<array>
   <string>(My Developer ID).*</string>
  </array>` is this what I should see?

Comment: What do you see under <key>DeveloperCertificates</key>?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman there is none

Comment: That's plain wrong. Try tracking down all App Store provisioning profiles, deleting them and creating a new one. Verify that the new one has a developer certificate.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42162/discussion-between-domenico-and-rhythmic-fistman)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Screenshot that you have attached for errors & provisioning profile, looks like the problem is with the "Case Sensitive" name.

Profile : `com.slogangen.slogangen`

Error : `com.slogangen.SloganGen`

From apple documentation:

`Typically, the bundle ID in your Xcode project is a string formatted as a reverse-domain name such as com.MyCompany.MyProductName, where you replace MyCompanyName and MyProductName with your domain and product name. However, unlike domain names, app IDs and bundle IDs are case sensitive.`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I found out that I had just changed the case of my app so that it would look better. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

1. Remove `armv7s` from valid architecture in build settings
2. Make sure you have a certificate for app store.
3. Check the bundle identifier to make sure that it is same as your certificates.

Comment: I can't find armv7s in build settings, I have a certificate for the app store, and the bundle identifier is correct.