# iOS & XCode5 App publishing fails - Error ITMS-9000: "The binary you tried to upload was invalid"

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, app-store, app-store-connect

I was already looking through some other threads here with the `ITMS-Error 9000`, but they didn't help me to get my App passing the submission to the App Store.

- I have NO errors or warnings inside XCode.
- The App is perfectly working on iOS Devices & Simulators.

**EDIT: What I have already tried:**

1. Changed Deployment Target from iOS 7.1 to 7.0
2. Checked the Bundle ID in iTunesConnect and inside Xcode
3. Checked for any errors and warnings --- removed / fixed them

[image]

Do you have any additional ideas what it could be? Without any errors or further information it is hard to find out what the reason is.

UPDATE2::
If I try "just" to "Validate" instead of "Distribute" in the organizer after Archiviing it i get the following Error 
[image]

Comment: Have you checked the app history in iTunes Connect? Make sure the bundle ID is exactly the same, including the upper and lower cases.

Comment: @Neeku - thank you for this Advice - already checked it a few times... everything matches.

Comment: I see. Did these answers help at all? I saw another post an hour after yours, having the same issue. I wonder if that's a temporary problem from Apple's side.

Comment: I currently have the exact same problem..

Comment: I feel like this is a temporary issue from their side. Several people having the same issue at the same time is a bit odd.

Comment: Guyzz…I am still getting this error, HAve any of you ppl able to upload your binary from yesterday…or is it something wrong with mine

Comment: Follow my guid to solve your issue ;) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21853083/invalid-signature-invalid-binary-on-itunes-connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called today the Apple Developer Support and i get one very very simple answear to this issue.

You have to create all your certificates, provisioning profiles etc with Apples SAFARI browser.

It is not working "always" proper with Mozilla Firefox or other Browsers. So if you get such an error, try to recreate it with Safari! It worked like a charm!

Comment: Not necessary, I used a mac and I had created ALl of my Certificates and Profiles through safari,..Still I had to create it once again after Apple server was up

Comment: @Geet yes but i created my profiles and certs with firefox. Till last week without any problems. After trying it with Safari it worked like a charm

Comment: It wasnt the issue of a safari or firefox, it was the issue of certificates being created within that time, Had u created your certificates recently, then you would have faced the problem regardless of the medium

Answer (score 6):

Its an Issue with Apple's Server I tried validating the app it said  "Unable to process app at this time due to general error" a quick search about it on SO said its got nothing to do with our code or project but some process running at Apples server

Comment: To see if Apple services are working well take a look at this link:
https://developer.apple.com/system-status/

Comment: I was trying again but didn't work so I Revoked My Certificate and then did a refresh from Xcode>Preference>ViewDetails of my account…, After that I  It asked me to request a new Certificate which I did.

After this I recreated my provisioning profile with the new Certificate and tried to submit my App it went Smoothly, I suggest if You had created a Certificate recently try to Revoke and edit your Profile for with the new certificate, it would work then.

Comment: Yes you are right! That was a problem with the Apple Servers. Thank you all. I thought "ITMS-9000" is caused because i did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your binary icons does not meet as per apple's human interface guidelines.

[image: App Icon Format]

Answer (score 0):

It most probably seems to be the issue with the profile you are signing your app with. You got to make sure that your are signing the app rightly with proper distribution profile. Also check out for the bundle identifier and make sure that it is same as the one you have given in itunes connect. 
Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20232907/xcode-application-loader-error-itms-900-invalid-provisioning-profile)!

Comment: the link contains a different error (with more detail also). I also get this error and I recreated my profiles and certs a few times now and also checked the app id. As it's an update this shouldn't have changed anyway though. Also it used to work in the past like that. So I hope it's an apple problem and will be resolved by waiting (on my side).

Answer (score 0):

You should be creating the binary with the simulator or some device connected.

**Try it:**

1. Unconnect iOS device from your Mac,
2. Dont select any simulator, just leave it as it is, iOS device option
3. Archive it
4. Publish it

Make sure you're using a provisioning profile for the App Store (not for Ad Hoc distribution)

Then select this profile when building your app.

Comment: I have followed your idea and disconnected my device - still the same error

Comment: Make sure you're using a provisioning profile for the App Store (not for Ad Hoc distribution)

Then select this profile when building your app.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess this all has something to do with Apple making system changes to prepare for iOS 8 and in doing so somethings got broken.

The issues look to have just been resolved by Apple. I just successfully submitted an app that was previous showing the same problem you had.  If you look at your Provisioning Profiles, you should notice that Apple has removed your app's previous Distribution Profiles.

To get your submission working again, all you have to do is recreate your App Store and Ad Hoc provisioning profile, but **make sure to use a new name** and you should be good to go. You were not alone on this one. A bunch of people experienced the same problem and there were a lot of posts about it on the official Apple Dev forums.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Distribution Profile that you are signing your app with at iTunes Connects. make sure that it is still  valid. I had same issue couple days back and after a struggle , i found out that somehow my provisioning profile was not valid anymore. Creating a new profile and submitting app with it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Apple have deleted corrupted provisionning, you just have to regenerate it and make submission works again !**

- Connect to your iOS Developer
- Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles
- Provisioning Profiles / Distribution
- Here you can see some certificates missing. You have to re-create (Distribution / AdHoc). *Note, you have to change certificates name !*

In Xcode, refresh your certificates, set the right one in Build Settings, and **submit**...